# Magento, Split sitemap.xml and cron job

Tags: magento, split, cron, sitemap

I am trying to split my sitemap.xml because Google webmaster tools only allows sitemap.xml to be less than 50k urls. I have the following code placed in:
**app\code\local\Mage\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php** to split sitemap.xml if the file contains more than 50k urls.

```
public function check_counter(&$io) {
static $counter;
$counter++;
$tRec = 50000; // total record per file

if ( ($counter % $tRec) == 0 ){
    $io->streamWrite('</urlset>');
    $io->streamClose();
    $filename = preg_replace('/\.xml/', '-'.
         round($counter/$tRec).
         '.xml', $this->getSitemapFilename());
    $io->streamOpen($filename);
    $io->streamWrite('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n");
    $io->streamWrite('<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">');
}
```

Everything works fine if I manually generate sitemap from Magento admin panel. It will create 2 files: **Sitemap.xml** (50,000 urls) and **Sitemap-1.xml** (12,312 urls)

I have setup the cron job to generate sitemaps every night. The problem is the cron job seems doesn't follow the code. It generates 2 files: **sitemap-1.xml** (I don't know how many, but definitely more than 50,000 urls, because google gives me an error says i have too many urls in this file) and **sitemap.xml** (couple hundred urls.)

What's wrong with the code? Or what's wrong with my cron job?

EDIT:

I put

```
$this->check_counter($io);
```

after each

```
$io->streamWrite($xml);
```

in

```
public function generateXml()
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing where you're calling check_counter from.

Comment: Default Magento sitemap extension is bugged (very slow/memory consuming).
I suggest you to use this extension (it support split ):
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/xml-sitemap-generator-splitter-7228.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me even manually.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but here is our solution for this issue.

We created a separate module to house the changes (not just moving it to local) ex: Namespace_Modulename

In the app/etc/modules/Namespace_Modulename.xml file we added a depends statement as follows:

```
    <depends>
        <Mage_Sitemap/>
    </depends>
```

Once we did this, the cron job worked properly.